# How to deal with listening to multiple changes using useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have multiple values I'm listening to and different actions to perform for those values. Problem is that I don't know what is the best way to prevent them from running on first render. Let's say I have:

```
const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState();
const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState();
const [thirdValue, setThirdValue] = useState();
const [fourthValue, setFourthValue] = useState();
const [fifthValue, setFifthValue] = useState();

useEffect(()={
   // action 1
},[firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue])

useEffect(()={
   // action 2
},[fourthValue])

useEffect(()={
   // action 3
},[fifthValue])
```

I looked into `isMounted = useRef(false)` example, but it works only if you have just 1 extra `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I looked into `isMounted = useRef(false)` example, but it works only if
> you have just 1 extra `useEffect`.

I think you are assuming you ***must*** update the `isMounted` ref within the first `useEffect` hook in the component.

Remember that all hooks are called each render cycle ***in the order they are declared***. If you want all three `useEffect` hooks to skip the initial render then don't update the `isMounted` ref until *after* all three have had a chance to run at least once.

Example:

```
const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState();
const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState();
const [thirdValue, setThirdValue] = useState();
const [fourthValue, setFourthValue] = useState();
const [fifthValue, setFifthValue] = useState();

const isMountedRef = useRef(false);

useEffect(()={
  // action 1
}, [firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue]);

useEffect(()={
  // action 2
}, [fourthValue]);

useEffect(()={
  // action 3
}, [fifthValue]);

useEffect(() => {
  isMountedRef.current = true; // <-- now mutate the ref
}, []);
```

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know that they are always called in same order. I also came across examples where `isMounted` was used with `useRef` and some with `useState`. Is there a difference in performance between them or it's a matter of preference?

Comment: @Alyona I don't think there's any difference in performance, but how/when they update is different. React refs can be mutated at any point ***during*** a render cycle and the change is immediate and doesn't trigger any rerenders, where as enqueued state updates aren't processed until the end of the render cycle and will trigger a rerender. It probably is a mix between preference and when the timing of the "isMounted" value changing is desired.

Answer (score 1):

If the expected functionality is to prevent execution of a code inside useEffect during initial rendering, just keep the code inside an if condition which will check if each of the states have the values that is not the initial value of that state.

Ex:

```
const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState(null);
const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState(null);
const [thirdValue, setThirdValue] = useState(null);
const [fourthValue, setFourthValue] = useState(null);
const [fifthValue, setFifthValue] = useState(null);

useEffect(()={
if(firstValue!==null&&secondValue!==null&&thirdValue!==null){
   // action 1
}
},[firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue])
```